# How to compare number with another number in an Array? [c]

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

I would like to know if the number the user enters is number in the array.

Here is my code:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int my_arr[10];
    int secnum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&my_arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the another number");
    scanf("%d",&secnum);

    if(my_arr[i] == secnum)
    {
        printf("an ex");
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I compare a number with another number in array?

Note: I don't know pointers so I need to do it without pointers.

Comment: Please descrip, doesn't work. Never ignore the return value of   `scanf()` always check.

Comment: where is `if` check in your code?

Comment: error:subscripted value is neither array nor pointer. I dont need to use in pointer and I dont undersand the error. How to fix it?

Comment: @Pawan in the seond code if(my_arr[i]==secnum)

Comment: in your `main()` function, where and how are you using `if` check?

Comment: Do you want to check the presence of a number in `main()` only or in a different function?

Answer (score 1):

Why it doesn't work and what is wrong with the code?

- You are comparing against just one value rather than all the array elements.
- The value of `i` after the `scanf` loop is 10 so `arr[i]` would exceed the 
  array and could cause Illegal memory access.

Check the comments in the program.

```
#define ARR_SIZE 10
int main()
{
    int my_arr[ARR_SIZE];  //Use ARR_SIZE because if ARR_SIZE changes, 10 won't causing unforseen errors.
    int secnum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&my_arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the another number");
    scanf("%d",&secnum);

    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE ; i++) // Ensures you are comparing secnum with each array element.
    {
        if(my_arr[i] == secnum)
        {
            printf("an ex"); //Do you wish to break here because one you find a match, the goal is attained :)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the loop, i is equal to `ARR_SIZE` (`10`). So you compare `my_arr[10]` with `secnum` (`0`). But `my_arr[10]`, while syntactically correct, points to an undefined value because the size of the array is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ARR_SIZE 10

 int main()
{
int my_arr[10];
int secnum = 0;
int i = 0;

for (i=0;i<ARR_SIZE ; i++)
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&my_arr[i]);
}
printf("Enter the another number");
scanf("%d",&secnum);

for (i=0;i<ARR_SIZE ; i++)
{
    if(my_arr[i]==secnum)
    {
        printf("Given number is in array\n");
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. For this ex I need to check this in another function

Comment: @NoNameP then, please add it as a constraint to your question, together with other restrictions and specifications.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by OP in comments to one of the answers, OP apparently need a routine to check for the key in an array.

So once we have stored an `array` and have accepted a `key` to search, we need to pass this `array` and `key` to a search function which will return `true` or `false` depending upon whether the `key` is present in the array or not.

```
#include <stdbool.h>    // We need this for `true` and `false` bool values

bool search(int [], int);    // Function declaration

/**** Function Definition *****/
bool search(int numbers[], int key)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        if(numbers[i] == key)
            return true;

    return false;
}  

/** Calling search function from main **/  
...
if(search(my_arr, secnum))
    printf("Number found in array!\n");
else
    printf("Number could NOT be found in array!\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a value in an array you should iterate through it and compare each value with the wanted number. You should also check the return value of `scanf()` to control how many item did it actually read. See if this reviewed code is helpfull:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 10

int read_numbers(int a[], int size) {
    int i = 0;
    int r = 0;
    while ( i < size ) {
        printf("Please, enter a number (%d of %d): ",i+1,size);
        r = scanf(" %d",&a[i]);         // the space before will ignore any trailing newline
        if ( r == EOF ) break;          // if scanf fails return
        if ( r != 1 ) {                 // if user don't enter a number, repeat
            printf("Wrong input!\n");
            scanf("%[^\n]*");            // will read and ignore everything lweft on stdin till newline
            continue;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return i;       // return size, unless scanf fails
}

int find_number(int a[], int size, int x) {
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < size  &&  a[i] != x ) ++i;
    return i;   // if x isn't in the array returns size
}

int main()
{
    int my_arr[ARR_SIZE];
    int secnum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    n = read_numbers(my_arr, ARR_SIZE);
    if ( n < ARR_SIZE ) {
        printf("Warning, only %d numebers read out of %d!\n",n,ARR_SIZE);
    }  // if happens you have uninitialized elements in array

    printf("Now, enter the value you want to find.\n");
    if ( read_numbers(&secnum, 1) != 1 ) {      // reuse the function
        printf("Sorry, an error has occurred.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    i = find_number(my_arr, n, secnum);     // If all went right n==ARR_SIZE
    if ( i < n ) {              // a match has been found
        printf("Found!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not found.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```